# How to Calculate leave balance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having Leave_type model. Using this model I have assigned such as Annual leave 20 days,Sick leave 5 days.

Another model is leave_apply,In that I have following attributes,such as,

:teacher_id,:leave_type_id,:leave_balance,:from_date,:to_date,:day_count, :comment
For example, If a teacher took 5 days leave from her/him annual leave.the leave balance should shows the remaining leave days such as 5 (i.e 10-5). Which is based on leave_type and teacher.I have following code , but it won't work.

Controller

```
if params[:balance].present? and params[:teacher].present?     
       @counts = LeaveType.find(params[:balance]).leave_count 
       @leave = LeaveApply.find_by_teacher_id_and_leave_type_id(params[:teacher],
                                                                params[:balance])

          @count = @counts - @leave.day_count


      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
```

Model

```
class LeaveApply < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible  :teacher_id,:leave_type_id,:leave_balance,:from_date,:to_date,:day_count,
                    :comment

    #associations
    belongs_to :leave_type   
    belongs_to :teacher
end
```

Please Help me..

Comment: what is the error/unexpected behavior that you are getting? wrong number , Rails error...

Comment: Yes, please show us the error message you are getting - that will help us pinpoint which line of code is the one that is causing you grief.